# getting html radiobutton value using regularexpression

Tags: asp.net

```
<input type="radio" value="_xxxx" checked="" name="_abcde">
```

I need to get value from the above html using regular expression,if I give input as above html code.

Comment: Above HTML Code? please paste it.

Comment: <input type="radio" value="_xxxx" checked="" name="_abcde">

Comment: Why do you need a regex (it is *not* the best tool to parse html)? Where does this html come from? (please [edit] the answers into your question)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will find all value attribute values `(?<=\bvalue=")[^"]*`